# How to define multiple file downloads for a single library in drush make

Tags: drush

I am trying to create a make file for the closedquestion module following the instructions in the [readme](http://drupalcode.org/project/closedquestion.git/blob/refs/heads/7.x-2.x:/README.txt#l49) file.

I know the below configuration snippet doesn't work - due to the fact that I am overwriten the first declared download with the second.

```
; Closedquestion libraries

; * Put jquery.json in sites/all/libraries/jquery-json
;   get it from: http://code.google.com/p/jquery-json/
;   This should result in one of the files (you might have to rename it):
;   - sites/all/libraries/jquery-json/jquery.json.js
;   - sites/all/libraries/jquery-json/jquery.json.min.js

libraries[jquery-json][download][type] = "file"
libraries[jquery-json][download][url] = "http://jquery-json.googlecode.com/files/jquery.json-2.3.js"
libraries[jquery-json][download][sha1] = "2bf6472f96791d6f8a5a405fe6eabe87babf8931"

libraries[jquery-json][download][type] = "file"
libraries[jquery-json][download][url] = "http://jquery-json.googlecode.com/files/jquery.json-2.3.min.js"
libraries[jquery-json][download][sha1] = "2a4615b93c65dd50f92117c570121035a0327fee"
```

I also tried renaming the second to jquery-json-min & defining a directory_name, but that just throws an error that the folder already exists as would be expected.

```
libraries[jquery-json-min][download][type] = "file"
libraries[jquery-json-min][download][url] = "http://jquery-json.googlecode.com/files/jquery.json-2.3.min.js"
libraries[jquery-json-min][download][sha1] = "2a4615b93c65dd50f92117c570121035a0327fee"
libraries[jquery-json-min][directory_name] = "jquery-json"
```

Any input on how this could be solved would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close, you should use destination instead:

```
libraries[jquery-json-min][download][type] = "file"
libraries[jquery-json-min][download][url] = "http://jquery-json.googlecode.com/files/jquery.json-2.3.min.js"
libraries[jquery-json-min][download][sha1] = "2a4615b93c65dd50f92117c570121035a0327fee"
libraries[jquery-json-min][destination] = "libraries/jquery-json"
```

Comment: Very nice, worked as a charm.